# Creating Eclipse Keylogger Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, keylistener, keylogger

Does anyone know if it would be possible to create an eclipse plug-in that would log all your keystrokes (a keylistener/keylogger) in the editor and save this data to a text file?

I would like to eventually analyse that data and provide useful information.

I have never made a plug-in before so I was hoping someone with more experience could let me know if its possible.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to every key event in the current Eclipse using a filter on the current SWT `Display` object - something like:

```
Display.getDefault().addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener()
  {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event)
    {
      // TODO handle key down here

    }
  });
```

which gives you a basis for what you want to do.